# how to check if desktop notification value in chrome settings?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I use Desktop Notification of Chrome in a Web based Chat Application when user get some messages. There are three options in content settings of chrome for desktop notifications
, i need to read these setting values by java script for notice user when notifications is not allowed, 
so how can i do that or impossible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access these settings with the [content settings module](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings.html).

You might use `chrome.contentSettings.get()` and read the [notifications property](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings.html#property-notifications).